# Как исключить JUnit тесты из Jar при сборке Ant-ом

Tags: java, jar, ant, junit, юнит-тесты

Здравствуйте

Собираю проект Антом. Решил добавить прогонку юнит-тестов в билд скрипт. Добавить - добавил. Но оказалось, что они попадают в финальный jar файл. Исключать файлы по маске *Test*.class не могу - есть классы с такими именами.

Проблема появилась, когда я пытался собрать тесты в отдельную папку - не находились классы, которые собственно и тестировались. Было примерно так:

```
<!-- Compiles the java code -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src1.dir};${src2.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
    <javac srcdir="${unittest.dir}" 
        destdir="${unitbuild.dir}" 
        classpathref="unitclasspath" 
        debug="true" 
        debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
</target>
```

Пока что собираю проект дважды - с юнит тестами и без:

```
<!-- Compiles the java code -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src1.dir};${src2.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="classpath" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
    <javac srcdir="${src1.dir};${src2.dir};${unittest.dir}" 
        destdir="${unitbuild.dir}" 
        classpathref="unitclasspath" 
        debug="true" 
        debuglevel="lines,vars,source" />
</target>
```

В jar запаковываю папку без юнит тестов. Но что-то тут явно не правильно :)

Comment: методом тыка, но сделал. Код тестов собирается в одну папку, код апликейшена в другую. Таргетом junit связал между собой. Так как папки разные, то классы junit не попадают в jar

Comment: в принцыпе можно билдить все в одну папку а потом или разделять файлы на 2 группы и упаковывать в архивы или сразу упаковывать по маске

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в сторону `<exclude>`, типа:

```
<fileset dir="${sources}" casesensitive="yes">
  <patternset id="nontest.sources">
    <include name="**/*.java"/>
    <exclude name="**/*Test*"/>
  </patternset>
</fileset>
```

Comment: Я не могу исключать по имени - у многих класов есть *Test* в названиию Более того, многие юнит тесты не имеют Test в имени.

Comment: Ну зачем так прямолинейно, маска допускает и каталог... Все равно юнит тесты собраны (наверное) в одном пакете

Comment: кстати, с каталогом вообще не получалось. Как показывают комментарии, можно исключать <exclude name="**/*Test*"/> таким способом, а <exclude name="{$Test}"/> не работает напрочь. Но ничего, начал собирать в другую папку, и все получилось)

Comment: Посмотрите примеры [масок](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) - там и не такое можно задать

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, то чего вчера не хватало